# ASP.NET file upload progress bar

Tags: asp.net

I've tired looking for an example of ASP.NET file upload progress bar without using flash or silverlight or ajax (just using iframe).

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NeatUpload is a pretty good solution. Depends on your definition of Ajax, but it does full page reloads with iframes and interpolates inbetween.

Comment: It can,if you want it to use it. But it works without it too.

Comment: Unfortunately they stopped dev on it back in 2011. It's a bit dated now.

Comment: Indeed. We actually started using blueImp https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Complete-code-example-using-blueimp-jQuery-file-upload-control-in-Asp.Net.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it without some Ajax or some other mean (flash, silverlight...) to query the server periodically for the status of the upload. Normally, browsers don't provide upload status in a form you can read on the client side with javascript.
Unless what you need is just an indefinite "loading" animation (that provides no information on the real progress of the upload)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem at work recently and ended up having to roll my own, simple C# file upload user control. The code is found on github here: 
https://github.com/CBCMusic/ajax-file-uploader

It uses an existing JS library to handle the progress bar & XHR2 file upload, and downgrades nicely for older browsers. No flash, just HTML5. Hope it helps...!